# macOS App different behaviour between Development and Release versions

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, wkwebview, nswindow

I created a macOS app which, upon pressing a button, launches another NSWindow with a WKWebView inside. While developing the app and launching it via the "Run" button in Xcode the WKWebView loads fine and displays the web page. But when I archive the app and export it as a .app file and run it independently from Xcode it does not load the WKWebView and only shows an empty NSWindow.

Does anyone know what the problem could be here?

Thanks a lot and best regards

EDIT:

I tested to launch another NSWindow with a ViewController in it and a simple label. This works fine. Here is the code:

```
myWindow = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name("Main"), bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "testWindow") as? NSWindowController
myWindow?.showWindow(self)
```

As soon as I replace the label with an empty WKWebView, the application now crashes when testing without Xcode. In Xcode it launches fine.

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000017781d5f58a0
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [5905]

VM Regions Near 0x17781d5f58a0:
    __LINKEDIT             0000000114a12000-0000000114a39000 [  156K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld
--> 
    MALLOC_NANO            0000600000000000-000060000339a000 [ 51.6M] rw-/rwx SM=ZER
```

Comment: why are you voting down my question? If you need additional details let me know or if the question is too obvious for you help me out please...

Comment: Please add the method didFailNavigation:withError and didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError of Wkwebview to detect the real error. Maybe you don'have add permissione to arbitrary url in your plist file

Comment: @christianmini thanks for your answer, I just figured it out. It was a linking issue I needed  to add webkit to linked libraries in build phases and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out, the problem was linking, I needed to add webkit to linked libraries in build phases and now it works fine.